# How to just invalidate the background of window, not any pixel of the client area?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

just want repaint the background, not any part of the client area.

Comment: You need to specify more detail in the context of the question, not just with tags. I assume you have a background window and foreground window, want to cause the background to repaint but not the foreground.

Comment: No, not two windows. every window in win32 has a background (background brush/wm_ereasebackground) and client area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The background is painted IN the child area of the window. IF the window uses child controls to draw objects (in its client area) then you could use the WS_CLIPCHILDREN style to ensure that the background painting of the parent window does not over-paint any children.

You'd need to just paint the relevent area on the parent window however, any InvalidateRect type call will cause any overlapping child windows to be repainted regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with [WM_ERASEBKGND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648055%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Example:

```
 HDC hDC = GetDCEx(hWnd, NULL, DCX_CLIPCHILDREN | DCX_CACHE);
 SendMessage(WM_ERASEBKGND, (WPARAM)hDC, 0);
```

Comment: send message will cause it repaint now, how can I just invalidate it, not paint it now?

Comment: You can invalidate the entire form or a rectangle from it, i'm not aware of any methods of invalidating only the background of the form.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "*not pixels of the client*" area, I assume you want to invalidate the **non-client** area?  If so, try using the `SetWindowPos()` function with `SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_DRAWFRAME` flags.